# Different delimiters for bash word movement

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a bash emacs-mode shortcut to move the cursor backword a particular number of arguments on the command line. To illustrate what I'm looking for, I'll use a specific example (where `[]` is the cursor):

**START:** `$ prog -v a/b/c d/e/f[]`

**GOAL:** `$ prog -[]v a/b/c d/e/f` or `$ prog -v[] a/b/c d/e/f`

Ideally, I'd like to efficiently tell bash to move the cursor back *n* arguments, where an argument is a continuous string of non-whitespace characters.

What I've tried:

- Sitting on <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> for long enough gets me to where I want to be, but is inefficient.
- <kbd>C-a</kbd>, then sitting on <kbd>right-arrow</kbd> for long enough. Also inefficent.
- <kbd>M-b</kbd> goes back what readline considers to be a "word," which in practice seems to stop at spaces, slashes and dashes. But, I only want it to stop at whitespace characters. For the given example, I'd have to use <kbd>M-b</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd> to get to where I want to go, instead of my desired two times.
- <kbd>M-7</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd> does <kbd>M-b</kbd> seven times, so it does increase efficiency, but it requires brain power to count the number of "word" separators. It's much easier for me to count whitespace breaks instead of whatever readline considers as "word" delimiters.

Ideally, I could specify the number of arguments to go back, and then tell it to go back; something like <kbd>M-2</kbd>+<kbd>M-b</kbd>.

@m0dular has pointed out that in vi-mode, <kbd>B</kbd> treats argument boundaries as I had hoped, but I'd like to stay in emacs-mode, and, I'd like to be able to specify the number of arguments to go back without repeating the go-back command itself.

*Note:* I originally [posted a version of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48668173/211029) on StackOverflow, but since it's not directly related to programming, they suggested I come over here.

Comment: `M-2` `M-b` would work as you expect with `zsh` (`zsh` also has a framework where you can choose between different styles of _words_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always bind `vi-backward-bigword` to <kbd>Alt+B</kbd> (and `vi-forward-bigword` on <kbd>Alt+F</kbd>) to have the behaviour you'd expect (same as in `zsh` which also lets you choose between different word styles):

```
bind '"\eb": vi-backward-bigword'
bind '"\ef": vi-forward-bigword'
```

And Then you can use <kbd>Alt+2</kbd> <kbd>Alt+B</kbd>.

There are also `shell-backward-word` and `shell-forward-word` that skip over shell tokens. For instance, in:

```
cmd "first arg" $(echo second third)
```

`"first arg"`, `$(`, `echo`, `second`, `third` and `)` are all shell tokens. If you quote that command substitution (as you generally want to), it becomes one shell token.

Comment: I gave this a shot. Bingo! I created `~/.inputrc` with: `"\eb": vi-bWord` and `"\ef": vi-fWord`. I'm not sure why I had to use those abbreviated versions (I used `bind -P` to see what commands were available to me. Note to others: the keybindings seem to be set per editing mode [`-o`].) Now `M-3`+`M-b` does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can come with the `readline` library's emacs-mode keyboard shortcuts would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> to search backwards for `v` and place the cursor there.  You can also search forward from the cursor location with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> if your cursor is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I didn't know about this one, and I'll probably use this in certain situations. However it depends on me selecting the right character to go back to, and that means I'd have to scan the line to make sure the "right" character isn't used anywhere else. This was helpful though, none the less!

Comment: Generally when anything more adroit is needed, I just mash `^X`,`^E` and edit my commandline in `vim` (or whichever editor is configured in the `EDITOR` environment variable).

Comment: Why not use the same character-search shortcut to search for spaces directly?  `Ctrl-Meta-]` `<space>`

Comment: `M-2 M-C-] <space>` does get me to where I want to be, and is in emacs mode. The only potential improvement I'd hope for is the ability for consecutive whitespace to be considered as a single argument separator. E.g. if the command line contained `prog -v a/b/c <several spaces>         d/e/f[]`, then I wouldn't have to count the spaces in order to get back to `-v[]`

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question about how to navigate using `readline`, the default mode for which is emacs-style movement.  You might be interested in doing `set -o vi` for vi keybindings.

In your example with `set -o vi`, you could do either:

<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>

Or:
<kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>

Or just keep mashing <kbd>B</kbd> until the cursor is where you want.  Or just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to edit your command in `vim` and `:wq` that to run it.  The possibilities are endless, really.

Comment: This is another viable workaround for the problem, and is almost 100%. I want the ability to go back a certain number of arguments, where arguments are delimited by whitespace. I don't want to have to select a particular character to go back to (e.g. `v` in the example). Mashing `B` in vi mode seems to respect the desired argument boundaries as I'd like, so it's almost perfect (although I wish I specified emacs mode, because I really don't want to learn an entire new mode just for this). Is it possible to specify the number of arguments to backup using some variant of `Esc-B-B`?

Comment: Edit: no <kbd> in comments =T

Yes, `vi` can do anything ;)  To go backwards to whitespace, you can do `F`-`Space`.  You can repeat the last movement command with `;`.  Or, you can preface a movement command with a number, e.g. to go backwards 3 spaces: `3`-`F`-`Space`

Comment: You're right! Indeed, `2 - B` is exactly what I wanted. Just that I'm not currently comfortable in vi land, and learning vi seems like a steep price to pay for such a convenience. This is embarrassing for us emacs users -- vi can do something that emacs cannot do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `emacs` can do this, I'm just not the person to be able to answer that.  Maybe something like the @JigglyNaga comment above?